# Click to go to contact record from report

Tags: contacts, civireport

When i am viewing contacts in a civireport if i click on the persons contact name i am taken to the "view contact detail report" which is basically the Constituent Report (Detail). Is there a way to go the the persons contact record directly from the report and not have to be referred to the Constituent Report (Detail)?

this is the url it takes me to when i click on someone from the report that refers me to the constituent detail report: /civicrm/report/instance/2?reset=1&force=1&id_op=eq&id_value=6732

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension should help with your query –

https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-drill-down